# Passing a parameter to methode in task flow from jsff page

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, adf-task-flow

I am using task flow which contains the a login page (jsff), a methodeCalll (which return the department id), a router which accept the parameter from method and decide which page will open.

- the login page has two fields, userName, and paswrd, and a button (login) which perform login. I have enabled adf security and make datasource on weblogic server, the user and paswrd are from database
- the method is accepting a parameter String type (userName) and return int type (departmentId), method reside in APPmoduleImpl class, I want to pass the (userName) to method.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pageFlowScope variables to pass parameters.